# How to write array of struct with foreach in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, foreach

In here I can't use `foreach`:

> `Error    CS0030  Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApplication5._3.Struct.Sach' to 'int'

How can I fix it?

```
public struct Sach
{
    public string TenSach;
    public string TacGia;
    public string GioiThieu;
    public int ID;
    public void nhapdulieu(string q,string w, string e, int r)
    {
        TenSach = q;
        TacGia = w;
        GioiThieu = e;
        ID = r;
    }
    public void Insach()
    {
        Console.Write($"Ten sach: {TenSach}\n");
        Console.Write($"Tac gia: {TacGia}\n");
        Console.Write($"Gioi thieu: {GioiThieu}\n");
        Console.Write($"Ma sach: {ID}\n");
    }
};


public class QuanLySach
{
    public static void NhapSach()
    {

        Sach[] sach1 = new Sach[4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nhap ten sach, tac gia, gioi thieu, id:");
            sach1[i].TenSach = Console.ReadLine();
            sach1[i].TacGia = Console.ReadLine();
            sach1[i].GioiThieu = Console.ReadLine();
            var vv = Console.ReadLine();
            Int32.TryParse(vv, out sach1[i].ID);
        }

        foreach(int bb in sach1)
        {
         // in here i cant use foreach but i dont know why?
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }  
    }
}
```

Comment: a `foreach` loop contains an Inner Cast of the `Collection[index]` to your `item`'s `Type`. in other words your `foreach( int bb in sach1)` tells the compiler that each `sach1` item is an int, while it is not. thats why you get the error. i suggest you read  this book https://www.amazon.com/Exam-Ref-70-483-Programming-MCSD/dp/0735676828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `foreach` incorrectly. Foreach loop will iterate trough sequence and your `bb` should be same type as base type for that sequence. In your case it should be:

```
foreach(Sach bb in sach1)
{
     // in here i cant use foreach but i dont know why?
}
```

Comment: Also, beware, you can only read data from bb. not write to it.

Comment: @bwoogie Exactly, he will need to generate new collection of `Sach` except if he want to update only fields of `bb` and he doesn't want to change `sach1`.

Comment: @VôTâm No problem. Does this post solved an issue? If solved can you please mark as answered?

Comment: i can fix this error :D and how to mark as answered?

Comment: :) Just click "OK" icon on the left side. Thanks